Trivial cofibrations of simplicial sets, which are bijective on vertices
Let $f\colon K\rightarrow K^{\prime}$ be a map of simplicial sets that is a trivial cofibration (i.e. a monomorphism and a weak homotopy equivalence), which is bijective on vertices. Is $f$ in the saturated class $A$ generated by the horn inclusions $\Lambda_i^n\hookrightarrow\Delta^n$ for $n\ge2$ and $0\le i\le n$? (Note that the reverse inclusion is easy.)
The proof of Proposition 6.1.2.6. in Lurie's HTT implies that we can find a morphism $h^{\prime}\colon K^{\prime}\rightarrow M^{\prime}$ in $A$ s.t. $M^{\prime}$ is a Kan complex and $h^{\prime}f$ is in $A$, yet nothing more. I believe this proof would look different if the answer to my question was yes, so I assume there are counter-examples, but I have not managed to find any. Note also that the proof implies that $f$ is in $A$ in case that $K^{\prime}$ is already a Kan complex, so a counter-example necessarily has $K^{\prime}$ not a Kan complex.

Let $S$ be the nerve of the category with a unique object and a unique non-identity idempotent endomorphism.
The unique morphism $\Delta^0 \to S$ is a monomorphism, a homotopy equivalence, and bijective on 0-simplices.
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the class of morphisms obtainable from the horn inclusions $\Lambda^n_k \hookrightarrow \Delta^n$ ($n \ge 2, 0 \le k \le n$) by pushout, retract, and transfinite composition.
I claim $\Delta^0 \to S$ is not in $\mathcal{A}$.
Indeed, the opposite is true: $\Delta^0 \to S$ has the right lifting property against the horn inclusions in question.
This is because any $n$-simplex ($n \ge 2$) of $S$ that has two or more distinct faces that are in the image of $\Delta^0$ must itself be in the image of $\Delta^0$.
So if $\Delta^0 \to S$ were in $\mathcal{A}$ then it would have the right lifting property with respect to itself and be an isomorphism – a contradiction.

By examining the construction in the small object argument, we can obtain a sufficient condition for an anodyne extension $f : X \to Y$ to be in $\mathcal{A}$.
Let $E_0 (X) = X$.
Given $p_m : E_m (X) \to Y$, let $i_m : E_m (X) \to E_{m+1} (X)$ be obtained by adjoining to $E_m (X)$ solutions for lifting problems of the form below ($n \ge 2, 0 \le k \le n$),
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Lambda^n_k @>>> E_m (X) \\
@VVV @VV{p_m}V \\
\Delta^n @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$
taking care not to add new solutions for lifting problems that already have solutions.
Let $E (X) = \varinjlim_m E_m (X)$ and let $i : X \to E (X)$ and $p : E (X) \to Y$ be the induced morphisms.
By construction, $f = p \circ i$, $i$ is in $\mathcal{A}$, and $p$ has the right lifting property against the horn inclusions $\Lambda^n_k \hookrightarrow \Delta^n$ ($n \ge 2, 0 \le k \le n$).
Thus, if $p$ is a Kan fibration, $f$ would be a retract of $i$ and hence be in $\mathcal{A}$.
So we need to solve lifting problems of the form below:
$$\begin{CD}
\Delta^0 @>>> E (X) \\
@VVV @VV{p}V \\
\Delta^1 @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$
Thus, it suffices to characterise when a 1-simplex of $Y$ is in the image of $p$.
But this is easy: it is the smallest set of 1-simplices of $Y$ that contains the 1-simplices in the image of $f$ and is closed under "composition" (i.e. is a face of a filler of a $\Lambda^2_k$-horn, $0 \le k \le 2$).
Thus, $f$ is in $\mathcal{A}$ if (it is an anodyne extension, bijective on 0-simplices, and) the image of the 1-simplices of $X$ generate the 1-simplices of $Y$ under "composition".

Thanks again. I believe the class of morphisms $X\rightarrow Y$ s.t. the images of the $1$-simplices of $X$ generate the $1$-simplices of $Y$ under "composition" (perhaps we should say composition and cancellation) is also saturated, so your sufficient condition is also necessary, thus giving a neat characterization of $\mathcal{A}$. In particular, any weakly contractible simplicial set $S$ with exactly one vertex and at least one non-degenerate edge should yield a counter-example $\Delta^0\rightarrow S$. That said, I'm slightly confused by your choice of $S$. Isn't that a $K(\mathbb{Z}/2,1)$?

The category with a free idempotent is contractible, the category with a free involution is not. The composition law is different: $e \circ e =  e$ vs $e \circ e = \textrm{id}$.

Of course... I was mixed up, sorry. Thanks again!
